# Creating a sitemap with all pages listed at once

Tags: dictionary, sitemap, visio

I'm trying to create a sitemap of my website which shows all the pages of my site all at once, with lines showing which pages link to where.

I created a sitemap using Microsoft Visio 2010, but the problem is that it shows only 12 pages at first and you have to double click on each page to expand it and see the pages it links to, which continues on and a page can be repeatedly listed by expanding other sites that link to it.

Does anyone know of how I can create a sitemap which shows all pages all at once, without needing to expand any further, and that shows connections between sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I too have pondering about making it, but please consider that for even small sites... Let's say 500 pages each with 50 links you get 25000 connections. It quickly gets very hard to visualize :)

Are you doing it to satisfy management or something like that, so they can visualize website structure? How large is your website?

Comment: Yeah, I maintain my University's website, which has around 800 pages.

Comment: Okay, so you need something visual virtual navigation map. i.e. where you can float/fly around and observe the links/urls, e.g like space traveling representation with planets(pages) and lines(links)?

I have seen some old research projects experiment with that. If I ever get time, I will add it to my own sitemap program :) I will try see if I have the links somewhere on a todo list if you wish?

But as it is, I don't have any suggestion that in "one view" can visualize 800 pages with all links without it looking very messy :(